# Getting purple screen after logging in, after updates

Tags: updates, 20.04, asus

I was working on Ubuntu 20.04, did `sudo apt update ; sudo apt upgrade` & restarted the system.

Now I'm getting a purple screen after logging in. Could anyone help?

I'm using an Asus PC.

Comment: Do you use VGA?

Comment: @MaxSilvester, Yes I use VGA.

Comment: Does it work with a different cable?

Answer (score 1):

I updated `.profile` file to add 1600*900 resolution, but somehow that was causing issue after login

Removed those lines & now able to login

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
sudo xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "1600x900_60.00"
```